# Вставная конструкция или уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения, вставная-конструкция

1. Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы, осуществляемые через границу — с российской территории, — так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты, используя тяжелые орудия, полученные из России.
2. Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы, осуществляемые через границу — с российской территории,  так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты, используя тяжелые орудия, полученные из России.

В первом предложении *с российской территории* — это вставная конструкция, отнесенная к придаточному.
Во втором (так напечатано на "Голосе Америки") — что это?
Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: _Употребление только одного тире возможно, если предложение перестроить: "Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы через границу – с российской территории, так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты._

В этом случае тире - интонационное?
А если бы второе тире поставили, то было бы уточнение, выделенное тире с двух сторон?

Comment: _Вставка выделяется паузами, и у нее меняется темп произношения, таким образом обозначается второй план речи. А встроенная конструкция получает основное фразовое ударение, и она участвует в построении первого плана._ 

Вставка - это вставная конструкция?  Встроенная конструкция - это что? 

Пожалуйста, София, приведите пример со вторым планом речи и пример, где _встроенная конструкция получает основное фразовое ударение, и она участвует в построении первого плана._

Comment: А  как  схема  может  ЗАФИКСИРОВАТЬ ?  На  схеме  может  быть  что - то  кем - то  показано.  Зафиксировать  может  фото  или  видео.

Comment: Схема зафиксировала(?!) — неверный перевод? Возможно, система зафиксировала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы, осуществляемые через границу – с российской территории, - так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты, используя тяжелые орудия, полученные из России.

Для обособления вставной конструкции используются два тире, вставка относится к обособленному обороту, поэтому перед ней запятая не ставится.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ О ВСТАВНЫХ КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ

1)  Русская грамматика тем и хороша, что предоставляет различные ФОРМЫ, которые автор может наполнить СОДЕРЖАНИЕМ по своему усмотрению.  Автор выбирает подходящую по смыслу форму – это его авторское право, –   включая те случаи,  когда ему хочется выразить свои эмоции.

2) Теперь о форме: Уточняющие и пояснительные члены предложения в ДОБАВОЧНОМ СООБЩЕНИИ относятся к группе ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫХ ЧЛЕНОВ, которые ПРИ ОТСУТСТВИИ СОЮЗОВ обособляются с помощью ТИРЕ.  Назвать такую конструкцию «вставкой»  с токи зрения семантики можно только условно, но с точки зрения формы это  та же  вставка с той же пунктуацией и той же интонацией.

Например: У шоссе стоял одинокий домик – около самого входа в туннель. Листья ландышей здесь необыкновенно сочные и крупные – величиной в ладонь.   И необычайный – смутный и зловещий – гул доносился от этой человеческой массы.

3) Нет сомнения, что  СОЧЕТАНИЕ  знаков для вставных конструкций и присоединительных членов, обособляемых с помощью тире, делается ПО ОДИНАКОВЫМ ПРАВИЛАМ.

4) Вывод.  Все частные утверждения по данной теме, не составляющие общую картину, не кажутся убедительными. Следует сначала определить грамматическую форму, а затем расставлять знаки препинания.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 29.07.14 Г.

Теория и похожие примеры для приложений

Одно тире ставится, если за  приложением в соответствии со структурой предложения следует ЗАПЯТАЯ,  в этом случае считается, что второе тире «ПОГЛОЩАЕТСЯ» запятой, например:

Проходя вдоль своего вагона – нашего временного жилища, мы увидели в окне знакомую физиономии.    Стоял чудесный апрельский день – лучшее время в Арктике, и мы отправились на прогулку. Мы объехали давно высохший пруд – глубокую, заросшую бурьяном яму, затем дорога пошла в гору. Я увидел бабушку, Николая Ивановича – соседа по квартире, сестру Нину.

АНАЛИЗ

(1)Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы через границу – с российской территории, так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты.

(2) Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы, осуществляемые через границу – с российской территории, – так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты.

Грамматика двух предложений по отношению к  уточняющему обстоятельству не меняется: в обоих случаях это уточнение, обособленное с помощью тире. Но разная пунктуация (пропуск второго тире) определяет разную интонацию и в конечном счете разное акцентное выделение слов.

В предложении (1)  вставка  обособляется с помощью тире, но  второе тире поглощается запятой.  Вставка интонационно встраивается в предложение, так на нее падает тоническое ударение в конце  первой фразы (с россИйской территории). Здесь вставка более значима, чем первое обстоятельство «через границу».

В предложении (2)  вставка входит в уже обособленное определение, она является как бы обособлением 2-го порядка, поэтому интонационно ее приходится относить на второй план и обособлять двумя тире (она идет как уточнение).

Answer (score 8):

А где Вы видите здесь вставную конструкцию?
Вставные конструкции не связаны с основным предложением ("Я уезжал — так уж случилось, — а она оставалась..."), а здесь явное уточнение — от широкого  понятия к узкому: через границу (какую границу? откуда именно?) — с российской территории.

Должна бы быть запятая, но, видимо, эмоции перехлёстывают, очень хочется уличить Россию, заменили интонационным тире, а второе тире уже ни к селу ни к городу, его здесь и быть не должно.
Так что с русским языком у журналистов "Голоса Америки" всё в порядке.

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько случаев, когда второе тире опускается.

1.Если после обособленного **приложения**, носящего пояснительный характер, по условиям контекста ставится запятая:

*Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор **— весы,** то понял бы источник ошибки.*

2.Для внесения ясности, если **приложение** относится к одному из однородных членов предложения:

*За столом сидели хозяйка дома, её сестра **— подруга моей жены,** двое незнакомых мне лиц, моя жена и я.*

3.Если по условиям контекста после **несогласованного определения, выраженного неопределенной формой глагола**, должна стоять запятая:

*Так как оставался один выбор **— потерять армию и Москву или одну Москву,** то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее*.

У вас уточнение, обособленное с помощью тире. Поэтому второе тире тоже необходимо.

Вообще пропуск второго тире скорее исключение из правила, и исключение не строгое. Правило гласит: второе тире может опускаться. Это значит, что и его наличие допустимо.

Comment: Рассуждения о строгих и нестрогих правилах и прочих разнообразных вольностях не кажутся мне корректными. (Всегда первый шаг - это определение синтаксической конструкции, а второй - постановка знаков препинания в соответствии с этим определением, а также с учетом интонации).  Употребление только одного тире возможно, если  предложение перестроить: "Схема зафиксировала как обстрелы  через границу – с российской территории, так и те, что ведут вооруженные сепаратисты.

Comment: В этом случае обособленный член ВСТРАИВАЕТСЯ  в общую интонационную структуру предложения, в то время как в исходном предложении мы имеем ВСТАВКУ, отнесенную на второй план речи.

Comment: Не улавливаю изменения интонации на месте тире. В обоих случаях интонационный центр - "как обстрелы... так и те", а тире разделяет единство "через границу с российской территории". Если мы говорим об обособленном уточнении, нужны симметричные знаки. Если о единичном интонационном тире, концепция меняется до невнятной. Я бы во всех примерах поставила два тире.

Comment: Чтобы улавливать интонацию, надо представлять, что такое интонационная модель предложения. Вставка выделяется паузами, и у нее меняется темп произношения, таким образом обозначается второй план речи. А встроенная конструкция получает основное фразовое ударение, и она  участвует в построении первого плана. А под "интонационным тире" каждый вообще понимает то, что ему нравится, нет общего мнения и определения. В вашем тексте много красивых слов, но все они изображают частное и очень субъективное понимание проблемы.  А должно быть обобщенное решение в комплексе - "смысл-грамматика-интонация".